# How to add a SHA hash containing a '+' to Content Security Policy HTTP header

Tags: hash, content-security-policy

I have added a hash 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=' to the CSP header on a site, only for Google Chrome to tell me to add that same hash:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 
>   'sha256-wIuuK5ba7OAcKAanTmQNfXsquALURJjbDNey9fYOgrk='
>   'sha256-bBHvtUsahvK4AUK9cudfQY9aAj/W36/whyrS/FEv5mg='
>   '**sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=**'
>   'sha256-URnF06gx6Q3vkDUa9InSpaMLXZIlvzLk9Vk3fkMetU0='". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('**sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=**'), or a
>   nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

My guess is this is to do with the + in the hash, since Chrome isn't complaining about the other hashes. I have tried replacing the + with %2B in the header but that results in Chrome telling me the hash is invalid and will be ignored.

How do I add this hash so that Chrome recognizes it?

Comment: Just found this question when searching for `47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=`, which happens to be the sha-256-hash of a 0-byte-input. At least when using java.security.MessageDigest...